# While loop with a boolean method

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

So, once I saw something like this, in Java:

while ( !booleanMethod( ) );

I was wondering, what this line does. Let's say that internally, the method modifies some attributes and creates variables, etc, but finally, it returns a truth value.
How the loop works in this case? And also, will the method be called?.
Thanks.

Comment: I will recommend you to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
 while ( !booleanMethod( ) );
```

don't have block. It will execute successfully.

But

```
while(false);
```

will give compile error;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method is called. However, the loop is useless unless the method does something interesting other than return a boolean. For example, lets make it count to 10.

```
int counter = 0;

public boolean go() {
    counter++;
    return counter < 10;
}

while (go());

System.out.println(counter); //-> 10
```

This is a rather verbose way to do something that can be expressed in a much more straightforward way. However, the important part is that the method itself has to do some sort of side effect, otherwise the loop will go on forever, or it'll never run.